# Здравствуйте. Не могу перенести из одного статического массива в другой все элементы, кроме максимального и минимального значений

Tags: c++

Все элементы массива Z(K) переписать в массив X, за исключением максимального и минимального. Испробовал несколько методов, вроде алгоритм  правильный, но программа работает криво именно при переносе значений в другой массив.
Вот мой код:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int a[100], b[100];
    int n=0;

    cout<<"vvedi kolichestvo znacheniy massiva: ";
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"vvedi znacheniya massiva ";

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    int min, max;
    max=a[0];
    min=a[0];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[max]) max=i;
        if(a[i]<a[max]) max=max;

        if(a[i]>a[min]) min=min;
        if(a[i]<a[min]) min=i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n-2; j++)
        {
            if(a[max]!=a[i] && a[min]!=a[i]) a[i]=b[j];
            else continue;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n-2; i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Так покажите код.

Comment: Вот смотрите, добавил код.

Comment: Нужно в массиве несколько максимальных, то нужно проигнорировать их все или только первый?

Comment: Вы max и min совсем неправильно ищете. Надо `for (i = 1; i < n; i++) if (a[i] > max) max = a[i]; else if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];`/ Ну, и копировать тогда очень просто `if (a[i] == max || a[i] == min) continue; b[j++] = a[i];`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде несколько ошибок:

1. Сначала вы присваиваете переменным max и min значения первого элемента массива, а затем в цикле, вы присваиваете им же значения счетчика.
2. Далее в цикле копирования вы копируете неинициализированные значения массива b в массив а, и потом выводите массив b.
   Вот не много подправил:

   #include 
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
   int a[100], b[100];
   int n=0;

   ```
    cout <<"vvedi kolichestvo znacheniy massiva: ";
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"vvedi znacheniya massiva ";

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    int min, max;
    max=a[0];
    min=a[0];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>max) max=a[i];
        if(a[i]<min) min=a[i];
    }
    int bi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (max != a[i] && min != a[i])
        {
            b[bi] = a[i];
            bi++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<bi; i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
   ```

   }

P.S. а если элементов будет больше 100, будет переполнение уже на этапе ввода начальных значений.